# My program crashes when I try to change private values from an object

Tags: c++

I'm quite new in c++ but I don't really see the problem in my coding (I guess you never do).
I'll try to be as specific as I can and try not to fill you with a huge ammount of code, so you don't focus what does not matter, but if you need more just let me know, please.
I'm sorry if most of the variables are in portuguese.

In this file, player.cpp I have this:

```
for(i=0;i<na.size();i++){ //this cycle allows me to find the object I want in a vector...
    if(na[i]->getID()==n){ //...of class objects
        l=na[i]->getX();
        c=na[i]->getY();
        flag1=1;
    }
}
na[i]->setCor(l-1,c-1); //when I try to alter this values I call a function of another file
```

It's the last line that's crashing my program
The function setCor is in navio.cpp and its respective header file:

```
void navio::setCor(int x, int y){
    xcor=x;
    ycor=y;
}
```

I have to do it this way because both xcor and ycor are private variables.
Before this, this function is successfully used, when I try to ecexute her a second time it crashes my program.

In order to help you understand a little bit of the context, here are the classes involved in this part of my code:

```
class player{
    vector<porto*> po;
    vector<navio*> na;
    int moedas;
public:
    ...//some functions I need
};

class navio{
    char tipo;
    int nSolM, nSol, aguaM, agua, cap, peixe, casas, id, xcor, ycor;
    bool pesca;
public:
    navio(string t, int n){
        this->id=n;
    }
    void setCor(int x, int y);
    ...more funtions I need
};
```

Comment: have you tried to attach debugger to debug this? Access violations are pretty clear cut. For instance are you accessing an out of bounds index? If you're accessing `i` outside the loop then it will be 1 off the end which is an out of bounds index value

Comment: "but if you need more just let me know, please" we do not need more, we do not need anything. You need us to help you and for that you better provide [mcve]

Comment: Run with Valgrind once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things in your code that are not clear. 
First, you are using

```
na[i]->setCor(l-1,c-1);
```

That instruction is out of the for loop and the index i is declare somewhere else out of the loop. The value of the *index i* is out of the *na* size when the program exits from the *for loop*.

Check it out.

Comment: We do know its value, it's one past the end of the container. (`i == size()`)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the problem is that you're accessing off the end of your array.

```
for(i=0;i<na.size();i++){
  ...
}
na[i]->setCor(l-1,c-1);
```

When the loop exits, `i` will be `na.size()`, so accessing `na[i]` is accessing one past the end of the array (valid elements are from `0` to `na.size()-1`).

Comment: Common mistake when used to VBA where indexes normally range from 1 and upwards. 
In C/C++ they start with 0 so the end is size -1 as sheltond has observed. 

Assume size = 10, then

VBA: for i = 1 to size -> i ranges from 1 to 10

C/C++: for (i = 0; i < size; i++) -> i ranges from 0 to 9

Comment: Thank you everybody! I feel so stupid I did not notice that ahah

Answer (score -1):

you forget to break from the loop after you find the object which ID is n, so after the for loop, i will always be na.size(), which past the end of the array. You need to add the break sign and add some code to deal with the situation which  the object can not be found.